# axios cancelled requests still showing in ngrok

Tags: react-native, axios, ngrok

I'm using [ngrok](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started) to expose my local webserver to the internet. In the terminal window for ngrok, you can see a list of the HTTP requests.

I'm using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for HTTP requests in my react native app.

I'm implementing a live search component, and I want to cancel previous request so the final results don't get messed up. I'm implemented the canceltoken in my requests. This is my code so far (simplified):

```
const cancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let source;

const liveSearch = async (searchQuery) => {
  try {
    if (source) {
      source.cancel();
    }
    source = cancelToken.source();
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `http://x.ngrok.io/search/${searchQuery}`,
      cancelToken: source.token
    });
    return response.data
  } catch (err) {
    if (axios.isCancel(err) {
      console.log(`cancelled request: ${searchQuery}`);
    }
  }
};
```

As you can see, if first check if a source exists. If so, cancel it, and create a new source. Then I do the request with the cancelToken as an object property.

When I run my app and check the console output of my app, I see 'cancelled request' correctly. But, in ngrok, I still see the HTTP requests for the 'cancelled' requests. An example:

In console output app (searching for 'hello'):

```
- cancelled h
- cancelled he
- cancelled hel
- cancelled hell
```

In ngrok terminal window:

```
- GET /search/hello 304 Not Modified
- GET /search/hell  304 Not Modified
- GET /search/hel   304 Not Modified
- GET /search/he    304 Not Modified
- GET /search/h     304 Not Modified
```

Is there something wrong with my implementation of the axios canceltoken? Or is it 'normal' that ngrok logs all requests, even the cancelled ones?